# Is there a replacement for the Doctrine Gedmo-Extension (Timestampable, Softdeletable ...) in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, gedmo-loggable

With prior versions of Symfony (<5), it was possible to automatically populate DateTime-fields on creation or when updating existing entries.

Example:

```
    /**
     * @var \DateTime $createdAt
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;
```

These annotations do not seem to have any effect if applied onto an Entity in a Symfony5 project. Has a replacement for the Gedmo-extension been released or is there a workaround to be used to avoid manually setting data fields with a current timestamp?

Comment: Are you using [`stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html)? It claims to function with Symfony 4.4 - 5.2 and is a method for integrating Gedmo with Symfony.

Comment: You have to [configure the listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/configuration.html#activate-the-extensions-you-want) for each extension.

Comment: @WillB. Yes, I have implemented and activated the doctrine-extensions-bundle.

Comment: Thanks @msg. Adjusting the stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml did the trick:

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            tree: true
            timestampable: true
            softdeleteable: true

Answer (score 2):

Editing /config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml did the trick. I had to activate the timestampable-listener:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            tree: true
            timestampable: true
            softdeleteable: true
```